# Get current System.Web.UI.Page from HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

This is actually a two part question. First,does the HttpContext.Current correspond to the current System.UI.Page object?

And the second question, which is probably related to the first, is why can't I use the following to see if the current page implements an interface:

```
private IWebBase FindWebBase()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current as IWebBase != null)
    {
        return (IWebBase)HttpContext.Current.;
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Crawling for IWebBase not implemented yet");
}
```

The general context is that some controls need to know whether they are executing as a SharePoint webpart, or as part of an Asp.Net framework.

I have solved the problem by requiring the control to pass a reference to itself, and checking the Page property of the control, but I'm still curious why the above does not work.

The compiler error is:
Cannot convert System.Web.HttpContext to ...IWebBase via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion or null type conversion.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

No, from MSDN on HttpContext.Current: "Gets or sets the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request."

In other words it is an HttpContext object, not a Page.

You can get to the Page  object via HttpContext using:

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

if (page != null)
{
     // Use page instance.
}
```

Comment: Down-Voted because incorrect. The answer with HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is correct!     If you do a Server.Transfer, HttpContext.Current.Handler WILL BE THE PREVIOUS PAGE, HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler WILL BE THE CURRENT PAGE

Answer (score 37):

You're looking for `HttpContext.Handler`. Since Page implements IHttpHandler, you'll obtain a reference to the currently executing page.You'll have to cast it, or at least try to cast it to the particular type you're looking for.

`HttpContext.Current` simply returns the singleton instance of HttpContext. Therefore, it is not and can never be, a page.

Comment: Just a note to anyone reading this. The answer below is the same but with an example (ie you use HttpContext.Current.Handler).

Answer (score 16):

You may want to use `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` if you want the precise page that is currently executing. For example, a request for Default.aspx is sent, but an error is thrown and you do a `Response.Transfer` to your custom ErrorHandler.aspx page. `CurrentHandler` will return the instance of ErrorHandler.aspx (if called after the error) whereas `HttpContext.Current.Handler` would return an instance of Default.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer : 
[Why HttpContext.Current.Handler is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054123/why-httpcontext-current-handler-is-null)

Maybe resolved your problem.

Comment: I'm using the same code for my work , but 
I was so annoyed because I was not aware of the details of work details.

So developed this code for my worke .
I thought that Put code Here To help  friends  that have my problem.

Thank John Saunders.