# Page.FindControl returns null in some arbitrary class other than the Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
TextBox txtEndUser = ((TextBox)page.FindControl("txtEndUser"));
```

Here `txtEndUser` always comes as null.

How can we fix this ?

Comment: Where do you write this code? in the asp.net page or in a SharePoint control, User control or where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround if you don't find the way using `FindControl` you can add public getter to your custom page class the have something like this:

```
WebForm1 myForm = (WebForm1)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
TextBox txtEndUser = myForm.GetEndUserTextbox();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I knew this method, I wanted to know the reason why the above code is not working.

Comment: @Puneet dunno, quick test with one Page and static class did work, so you probably have something "fancy" like Module? Or maybe you run the code before the `Page_Load` event?

Comment: I am running the code on a Button's OnClick event which is probably after Page_Load, but don't know why its not working.

Comment: @Puneet so please add this information to your question by editing it, plus give more code - give the code in that "arbitrary class" you have.

Answer (score 0):

If the page does not directly contains the `TextBox` control, then you wont be able to retrieve it with the `FindControl` function. You need to create a function that search contained containers for the target control ..

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that this code snippet is in `HttpModule` so probably, the request has not been handed out to a handler yet (for example, you're in `BeginRequest`).

Reference: [Why HttpContext.Current.Handler is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054123/why-httpcontext-current-handler-is-null)

Comment: Here Handler is not coming as null, Handler is perfectly set to the Page object and I am using other members of Page object. Rather, the txtEndUser is coming out as null, I am using this code in a Class method that is being called from a UserControl loaded in a Sharepoint Webpart which itself is in asp.net Page.