# Access current instance of Page from a static class

Tags: asp.net, static

Basic question - is it possible to access the current `Page` from a static class in ASP.NET?

I am thinking no, as google turns up no results.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58123/1475331.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Technically you could just get the current [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) for the request. Since [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) implements that, then you could check to see if it is one.

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

if(page != null){
    // Do something with page
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `HttpContext.CurrentHandler` to return the current HttpHandler for the request.  A Page class is simply a complex type of HttpHandler.

In order to access anything related to the Page properties though, you'll need to cast the result to type `Page`.

Honestly though, I would take Jeff's approach if possible, because by injecting the page reference in the method call, your method is much more testable (not to mention reliable, as you can use Page directly).  Relying on anything to do with HttpContext tends to make your code untestable.  Perhaps you're in a situation where you can't design the method like that, but it would be the way I would prefer to do it.

Comment: Agreed, I have a strong suspicion that httpcontext is a mess when it comes to threading aswell.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way has got to be passing the current page as a parameter to the method you're calling in the static class.

Comment: Yuck! HttpContext.Current it is then, unless you get a chance to refactor.