# Unknown web method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In the below code I have a textbox .My aim is when I focus on textbox it will call the server side code through ajax.But I got a error unknown web method `txtField_GotFocus` parameter name method name.Please help me to rectify the error.

design code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtField.ClientID%>").bind("focus", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%=Request.FilePath%>/txtField_GotFocus",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //alert("success message here if you want to debug");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                var rawHTML = xhr.responseText;
                var strBegin = "<" + "title>";
                var strEnd = "</" + "title>";
                var index1 = rawHTML.indexOf(strBegin);
                var index2 = rawHTML.indexOf(strEnd);
                if (index2 > index1) {
                    var msg = rawHTML.substr(index1 + strBegin.length, index2 - (index1 + strEnd.length - 1));
                    alert("error: " + msg);
                } else {
                    alert("General error, check connection");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtField_TextChanged" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

field.ascx:

```
public static void txtField_GotFocus()
{
    string foo = HttpContext.Current.Request["foo"];
    //code...
}
```

Comment: Do you need a WebMethod attribute on the method?

Comment: Your txtField_GotFocus method is static. You can't call a static method via ajax...

Comment: it shows txtField_GotFocus<br> parameter name method  name

Comment: @Jason WebMethos must be `static` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463189/why-webmethod-declared-as-static

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `[WebMethod]` annotation. Also i have modified your code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string txtField_GotFocus()
{
    string foo = HttpContext.Current.Request["foo"];//oops i got my super data
    //code...
    return "awesome, it works!";
}
```

Check this [`Article`](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/?bcsi_scan_F872AB84FAA8A40E=0)

Your refactored ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtField.ClientID%>").bind("focus", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%=Request.FilePath%>/txtField_GotFocus",
            data: "{foo:'whatever'}",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);//awesome, it works!
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can u check my ajax url and what to change i am working in field.ascx file

Comment: @user3224577 Are you shure your ajax reaches the webmethod without decorating it with `[WebMethod]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Data returned form Server is stored in `msg.d` field. If you return a single value, you should get it using `msg.d`. If you return a JSON serialized object you have to parse it using `JSON.parse(msg.d)`

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%=txtField.ClientID%>").bind("focus", function () {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<%=Request.FilePath%>/txtField_GotFocus",
           data: "{foo:'whatever'}",
           success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);//awesome, it works!
           },
            error: function (xhr) {
          }
       });
      });
    });
```