# How can I keep asp:button from reloading the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, page-refresh

I have multiple `asp:buttons` in my application that reload the page whenever they are clicked. How do I resolve this behavior while still allowing the function of the button to work? Besides looking weird when the page reloads, I  have a tab style navigation section that defaults back to the first tab every time a button is clicked. Here's an example of one button and the C# code that goes with it.

**HTML/ASPX**

```
<asp:Button ID="uxRequestFEMAResponseBtnT3" runat="server" Text="Generate Interim Response Email" OnClick="uxRequestFEMAResponseBtnT3_Click" />
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="uxFEMARequestDateTxtBox" runat="server" style="color: red; text-align:center;"></asp:TextBox>
```

**C#**

```
protected void uxRequestFEMAResponseBtnT3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        uxFEMARequestDateTxtBox.Text = today;
    }
```

**What I've tried so far:**
I have tried multiple fixes to resolve this issue. I initially thought I could resolve it by wrapping the entire body section (which includes all of the buttons) in a `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">`...'', but that did not work.  Second, I tried just adding `AutoPostBack="False"` inside the `<asp:Button..>` tag, but nothing changed. I then changed all of the `asp: buttons` to simple html `<input type="button"...>` with the same `onClick` event. This stopped the reload, but the functionality (adding DateTime to the textbox in the C#) no longer worked. I've seen several possible jQuery solutions, but I am not sure if that will resolve my issue either. I am pretty new to ASP.NET but this seems like a common problem that anyone using the `Web.Controls.UI` buttons would run into. Any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Comment: try adding `onClientClick="return false;"` on your button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid page refresh after button click event in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325211/how-to-avoid-page-refresh-after-button-click-event-in-asp-net)

Comment: Adding `onClientClick="return false;"` does not resolve this issue.

Comment: In regards to my question being a duplicate of "How to avoid page refresh after button click event in asp.net", I would like to note that: 1) That question was never answered (there is no satisfactory answer marked with a green check) and 2) As I mentioned in my question (see what I've tried so far) I have tried many of the suggestions in that question and none of them worked.

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page, but you want to fire a server-side event, you'll need to [do it with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852151/asp-net-webforms-calling-a-c-sharp-method-with-ajax) or other special Javascript request. Otherwise there is no means by which data can be transferred to the server to let it know the button was clicked.

Comment: @gwydion93 I suppose you have tried everything. And for so 1) the suggested edit is to stop the event from firing any server-side code. 2)  I just checked the code mentioned in the suggested duplicate(*i.e. is a combination of `UpdatePanel` and `ContentTemplate` without the `onClientClick` event*) on `Edge`,`Chrome`, `Firefox`, *`even IE`* and it is working as it should.

Comment: I have everything wrapped in `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" <ContentTemplate>` currently and removed `onClientClick` , but the behavior is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

few questions,

- Have you added the script manager and configured your button using RegisterAsyncPostBackControl method on page load?
- AutoPostBack should be always true. Other wise it will not trigger the server click event.

You can use jQuery. It'll definitely cover your requirement. But you have to write a web method instead of the button click event.

steps of Jquery

1. add jquery files and add a class to the button declaration
2. register the button click event

```
    $('.button-class').onClick(function()){
        //call to web method
    });
```

3. create a web method in your server side with contain the business logic
4. call the web method

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'PageName.aspx/MethodName',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d) {
                //set your values to the text box
                $('.textbox-classname').val(msg.d.returningvalue);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error! Try again...");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use updatepanels for this purpose...they will not refresh page and still exceute your click event

Comment: It's really weird; I have everything wrapped in `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" <ContentTemplate>` which I used a while back for `DropdownLists` with my `_SelectedIndexChanged` functions in the C#. It worked fine although I had to add `AutoPostBack="False"` in a few places. So why doesn't it work for the buttons?! I'm investigating it now.