# Asp.net Webform jquery ajax request not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am creating a hospital ERP project for my office. I have already added some features. in this time I need jquery ajax request for my project. I'm trying more but I am not a success this webform. so I need help expert person.
My Code Not working asp.net webform jquery ajax request.

Here is my code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Employee GetByEmployeeId(int Id)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    return employee;
}

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#saveButton').click(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Test.aspx/GetByEmployeeId',
                data: '{Id: ' + 1 + '}',
                success: function (respons) {
                    debugger;
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('fail')
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>


  <div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label runat="server" For="nametextBox">Name:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="nametextBox" CssClass="form-control"> 
 </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveButton">Save</button>
</div>
```

I am trying this but not working

Comment: In what way is it not working for you?

Comment: yes, it's not working

Comment: Make `GetByEmployeeId` as `static`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463504/3793448) to why `WebMethod` are marcked as static

Comment: I’m aggree with @Izzy. Make your webmethod static and pass fields you need as parameter.

Comment: You will also have to serialize object employee before returning it.

Comment: use static and this jquery alert message show ok but this cs file method not hit

Answer (score 0):

use static keyword in your web service.

```
public static Employee GetByEmployeeId(int Id){
Employee employee = new Employee();
return employee;}
```

Comment: use static and this jquery alert message show ok but this cs file method not hit

Answer (score 0):

Use this after debugger and then test what the service returns and their are not any employee on id=1 which you are passing. Thats why it returns null or error.
`var res = JSON.stringify(response);
                        var obj = JSON.parse(res);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make your method static as below:

```
public static Employee GetByEmployeeId(int Id)
```

to call a method using ajax you have to make the method static which is must.

then change button type from `submit` to `button`.
secondly use:

```
$('#saveButton').on('click', function () {
```

instead of:

```
$('#saveButton').click(function () {
```