# How do I determine if a request is the result of a postback?

Tags: asp.net

**Update**

I'm implementing a custom page caching solution and I don't want the request to be cached or retrieved from the cache if it's in response to a form submission or some sort of asp.net postback.

I'm trying to figure out if the current HttpRequest is a postback. Is there a way of doing this outside the context of a page or other usercontrol? In otherwords if I'm inside an HttpModule I don't have access to `this.IsPostBack` but I still need to determine if it is in fact a postback.

Also, are postbacks always "Post" requests or is that determined by containing form?

thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "outside the context of a page or other usercontrol" ?

Comment: You cannot have a postback without an ASP.NET page. Otherwise, all you have is a regular HTTP POST.

Comment: What does `IsPostBack` mean to you exactly?  Like, only when data is passed to the module... or what?

Answer (score 10):

Check the `Method` property of the `HttpWebRequest`.  Postbacks should be marked as `POST` in the `Method`.

Also, the way you did it in old-school asp was to check for expected post-back parameters in the body of the HTTP message (`Request.Form`).  You could check the content of the request for data that looks like postback parameter.  I'm not sure what object exactly you're working with, but if it's an `HttpWebRequest`, you might check the request stream from the `GetResponseStream()` method of the object.

Comment: For the lesser initiated:  `if (context.Request.HttpMethod != "POST")`

Answer (score 7):

```
if (Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // This is a POST
}
```

Comment: Ben McCormack has a better answer, but basically the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

The following static routine should be able to determine whether or not the current request is a postback. However, it will only work if you are executing an ASPX page, or derivitive thereof.

```
public class PostBackUtility
{
    public static Boolean IsPagePostBack
    {
        get 
        {
            Page pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            if (pageHandler == null) return false;
            return pageHandler.IsPostBack;
        }
    }
}
```

Should also note that `CurrentHandler` may not yet be initialised depending upon which stage in the request lifecycle you attempt to evaluate `IsPagePostBack`. I believe this method will only be valid between `HttpApplication.PostMapRequestHandler` and `HttpApplication.ReleaseRequestState`.

Answer (score 4):

An HTTPHandler will have access to the current HTTPContext. You use that to check a few properties (Request.RequestType, Request.URLReferrer) and manually decide if it's a PostBack.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the current page: [Get current System.Web.UI.Page from HttpContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123/finding-system-web-ui-page-from-httpcontext)

Then you can check for the Page.IsPostBack property.

Comment: This is good find and I'm up-voting it but it still wont work for me because I'm tapping into the pipeline before the handler gets associated with the request and therefore HttpContext.Current.Handler is always null.

Comment: During which step of page rendering do you need to know whether the page is postback or not?

Answer (score 0):

Like @ThatSteveGuy's answer HTTPHandler will have access to the current page and you can check for the request type.

Note HTTPHandler context will be avaliable only in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute in Global.asax.cs. Below is the code sample you can use it in your Global.asax.cs.

```
    void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType.Equals("POST"))
        {
            //Your code can go here.
        }
    }
```